# pinpoint word location (similar to battleship)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am given a grid which has scrambled letters but it has hidden words.  I must find the words location and depending if it's correct or not, the user is given certain points.

I currently have

```
def check_guess(puz: str, direct: str, words: str, rc: int, rip: int) -> 
   int:

    """
    """ 
    if words in puz: 
        return [get_points(direct, rip)]
    else:
        return 0
```

Basically if words (example :'cat') is in puz ('catan') than the user will get a certain amount of points.  However, they only get those points if they can identify which row/column (which I dubbed as "rc") the word is in and if that is incorrect, than they will get 0.  I don't know how to pinpoint the first letter in the word among this grid (dimensions are x by y).

NOTE: `get_points` is another function I created that gives the points.  Different direction gives different points (up, down, backward, forward).

I AM given two additional functions

```
def get_column(puzzle: str, col_num: int) -> str:
    """Return column col_num of puzzle.

    Precondition: 0 <= col_num < number of columns in puzzle

    >>> get_column('abcd\nefgh\nijkl\n', 1)
    'bfj'
    """

    puzzle_list = puzzle.strip().split('\n')
    column = ''
    for row in puzzle_list:
        column += row[col_num]

    return column
```

AND

```
def get_row_length(puzzle: str) -> int:
    """Return the length of a row in puzzle.

    >>> get_row_length('abcd\nefgh\nijkl\n')
    4
"""
    return len(puzzle.split('\n')[0])
```

Heres the video of my assignment for reference:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=70&v=zX0fBYDNYfw